# What is the ssh command PubkeyAuthentication=false?

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to understand what the `PubkeyAuthentication=false` actually is doing in the following command:

```
ssh -X -o PubkeyAuthentication=false notadmin@<DedicatedHost>
```

Is it turning off the PubkeyAuthentication? 
This is in a test procedure for to test Access Control and I am trying to understand what the is doing to by pass the PubkeyAuthentication.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! It is expected that you do some research first before posting a question. Have you, for example, read the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) of the `ssh` command? If the explanation of the option `PubkeyAuthentication` was not clear for you, can you edit your question to indicate *what* exactly was not clear?

Comment: It is not a command, with -o you specify options used for this specific invocation overwriting the Config file or defaults

Answer (score 3):

You are on the client machine, connecting to aSSH server. When you specify `-o PubkeyAuthentication=false` you are telling the server you DO NOT support ssh-key auth for *that* session.

SSH servers are most commonly setup to be accessed with a `ssh-key` or via `password` authentication. (Other methods are available)

If you want to use `ssh -X -o PubkeyAuthentication=false notadmin@<DedicatedHost>` on the client session, that server will need to support Password authentication. If the server does NOT support password authentication and you specify `-o PubkeyAuthentication=false` The server will fallback to any other authentication method available.

If the server has Password Auth disabled an PubkeyAuth enabled, you will not be able to connect using your SSH arguments.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `PubkeyAuthentication` it enables or disables the general SSH public key authentication for that use and on that host. As explained on [the documentation for `ssh_config` options](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) states:

> Specifies whether to try public key authentication. The argument to this keyword must be **yes** (the default) or **no**.

But in the command you provide, it seems that `false` is set:

```
ssh -X -o PubkeyAuthentication=false notadmin@<DedicatedHost>
```

Which *might* work, but am unsure. Would assume it should be `no` instead. But in your question you ask:

> This is in a test procedure for to test Access Control and I am trying to understand what the is doing to by pass the PubkeyAuthentication.

Most likely if this is in a test procedure—and someone developed those tests—then they wanted to force the SSH connection to not used SSH keys for authentication but rather use some other method; most likely a plain old password being typed in.

As for why that would be desired? Who knows. Without the context of the larger test context, nobody here can say. But I said what I said and based on what I know that line should *not* work since `false` is a literally false option.